# How to select a Combo Box in from web page in VBA Access?

Tags: ms-access, web-scraping, vba

I have been trying a lot of methods to try to select an option in a combo box in the web page. I am really stuck

```
Set AllHyperLinks = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks

If hyper_link.innerText = "UMSCP Phoenix 928" Then
hyper_link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 3

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4
' TROUBLE START HERE

ie.Document.getElementById("ProgramID").Value = "1146|928 Phoenix TouchPoints"

Set objButton = ie.Document.getElementById("ProgramID")
    objButton.focus
    objButton.Click
```

Here is the Webpage source code

```
<a href="#" id="changeimage" style="color: rgb(91, 108, 77); font-size: 13px; display: none;" onclick="ShowProgramChange(895,1)">928 Phoenix Legacy  </a>
<div style="display: inline;" id="programlistbox"><divabc><select onclick="ProgramID_onchange();" language="javascript" style="" name="ProgramID" id="ProgramID">
<option value="895|928 Phoenix Legacy" selected="">928 Phoenix Legacy</option>
<option value="1146|928 Phoenix TouchPoints">928 Phoenix TouchPoints</option>
</select>
</divabc></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to change the option. It seems the HTML has a statement leading to IE8 emulation which won't support querySelector (I think). There is a lot of ASP stuff going on so this may be tricky.

Also, make sure `<!doctype html>` is at the top of the document.

```
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set html = ie.document

Dim findString As String, replaceString As String
findString = "IE=EmulateIE8"
replaceString = "IE=edge"

ie.document.body.innerHTML = Replace(ie.document.body.innerHTML, findString, replaceString)
ie.document.querySelector("option[value='1146|928 Phoenix TouchPoints']").Selected = True
'    ie.document.getElementById("ProgramID").getElementsByTagName("option")(1).Selected = True '< Or this
```

And to fire the events:

```
ie.document.getElementById("ProgramID").Click
ie.document.getElementById("ProgramID").FireEvent "onclick"
```

---

You could also try:

```
IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "ShowProgramChange(1146,1); "
```

---

And with [selenium basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) (installing and then adding a reference to selenium type library)

```
Public Sub test()
 Dim d As New IEDriver
    With d
        .Start
        .get "youURL"
        'Other code
        .FindElementByXPath("//table/tbody//option").AsSelect.SelectByValue ("1146|928 Phoenix TouchPoints")
        'Other code
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```